# How to set href value in html using python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have been trying to solve this problem: i want to set url to html a tag using loop. I tried this way. But it gives me error which is "Reverse for 'i.menuResolve' not found. 'i.menuResolve' is not a valid view function or pattern name". 
In case, "i.menuResolve" returns url which is '/sales/profile' etc.

```
{% for i in userMenus %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'i.menuResolve' %}" ></a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help if anybody knows this error?

Comment: You really need to dive deeper into the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method or property that returns a URL, you don't need to use Django's [`{% url %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url). That template tag passes the arguments to Django's [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) function, but you don't need to do that if you've already got the URL.

Give this a try:

```
{% for i in userMenus %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ i.menuResolve }}" ></a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @Dulguuntur Happy to help! Be sure to accept the answer if it did the trick for you